# $error.required message is not getting reset on reset button : AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-validation, angularjs-forms

```
<div class="form-group">
 <input type="text" name="Name"
    data-ng-model="panNumber" required> 
    <p data-ng-show="loginForm.Name.$error.required && (loginForm.Name.$touched || submitted)"
    class="error-block">Kindly enter your valid 10 digit PAN Number</p>
</div>

<button type="reset" data-ng-click="loginCtrl.reset()">RESET</button>
```

**controller**

```
this.reset = function(){
            $scope.loginForm.$setPristine();
            $scope.loginForm.$setValidity();
            $scope.loginForm.$setUntouched();
          };
```

I have several fields in a loginForm, the problem is when user clicks on submit button without entering any data in any of the fields , all the error messages (required) are getting displayed. But when I reset button , the error messages are still present, they are not getting cleared.

I tried to debug a lot but not able to find the solution.I do not know what mistake I am doing.

Any help is appreciated !!!

Thanks

Comment: There is no required attribute added to input element. Add required attribute to input element and to the form tag, add "novalidate" attribute, to disable html5 validation

Comment: Hi , I have added it.

Comment: What is `submitted`?

Comment: I do not know exactly, this code is written by some one else, I am just trying to fix the bug.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer of this question by trying hard

just on click of reset button I need to call

```
$scope.submitted = false;
```